# Handling an optional boolean query parameter in Go

Tags: sql, api, go

I am working on an API where the `GET` request has a set of filters that can be applied to the data.

One of the filters is binary and non-mandatory.

My curent approach is using `*bool` instead of `bool` to differentiate between specified vs non-specified values of the filter.

```
var isVisible *bool
isVisibleParam := query.Get("is_visible")

isVisibleParsed, err := strconv.ParseBool(isVisibleParam)
if err != nil {
  isVisible = nil
} else {
  isVisible = &isVisibleParsed
```

And in SQL to cover that case correctly, I have `$param is NULL OR is_visible = $param`

The code above looks a bit ugly even though it works correctly. Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same?

Comment: To avoid the use of pointers where they are unnecessary use [`query.Has`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url@go1.19#Values.Has). (Or, since `query` is a map, you can do `val, ok := query[key]`, but then `val` is a slice and to get the actual value you need to do `val[0]`). In SQL, if `query.Has` (or `ok`) is `false`, then simply do not add that *condition*.

Comment: @mkopriva, our project still uses Go 1.16 (which is stupid and will be updated soon). So there is no `Has` yet :)

Comment: Then use the "special form" of assignment that maps allow, mentioned in the comment. That's what `Has` uses: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19:src/net/url/url.go;drc=bf5898ef53d1693aa572da0da746c05e9a6f15c5;l=911

Comment: I am wondering whether this is better than just using `Get` directly. The result is the same, isn't it? We just get the first parameter value if set and empty string else

Comment: D'oh  :facepalm:, you're right! That ought to be enough. That is, unless you want to support a "boolean flag", e.g. `?is_visible`, the same way CLI args usually do.

Comment: Another problem is that the method that is called (Get) expects the filter values as its arguments. I have to pass something as the `isVisible` argument value. This is why I decided to use `*bool` in the first place. Without `nil`, the filter is obligatory

Comment: Sounds like you've decided on a design that requires passing the output address, to some unspecified function, as an input argument. And you don't like that design, or do you want to keep it? I guess I'm not sure what the problem you need help with is. It might help sharing the actual code, and perhaps how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a bool pointer to differentiate "specified" vs "non-specified" looks good. On the SQL side maybe you could check if it's not null and only then append the condition to the query. As for the code, maybe condensing it makes it nicer:

```golang
var isVisible *bool
if isVisibleParam, err := strconv.ParseBool(query.Get("is_visible")); err == nil {
    isVisible = &isVisibleParam
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also considered this `err == nil` option as in your example, but I am wondering whether this is idiomatic in Go. I don't remember ever seeing such checks :) 

But I might be wrong though

Comment: `err == nil` or the analogous `err != nil`  are some of the most common checks in Go.  Very idiomatic.